# UItableView plist data ordering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Hi I have created a table view  which filled with a plist data , I need re ordering the cells ,  I mean instead of showing data like this :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

should be like this :

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

I am using this code :

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
    titles =  [[titles sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]] retain];
```

in this method :

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

but the result is something like this

```
1
5
2
4
3
```

how can I fix it ?

EIDTED :

my plist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
    <string>3</string>
    <string>4</string>
    <string>5</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Comment: Hey can you post more code ? name of your dictionary or array ?

Comment: Hi Mc.Lover have u use reuse identifiers like @"cell" in your table view ? i think problem is there it will rearrange ur cell pls make it dynamic. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

change `ascending:NO` to `ascending:YES` when creating the sort descriptor.

To provide any more advice you'd probably need to post more code. You should post how you're actually populating the data structure which acts as your data source, and how you are using that data structure in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Format your data like this (note that you can do this by creating a .plist with an array in it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Title of Array</key>
    <array>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>3</string>
        <string>4</string>
        <string>5</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then use this code to get it

```
NSDictionary *data = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
NSArray *array = [[names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```